# passing an object to function as a parameter

Tags: c++, oop

I tried to create a method that returns the summation of 2 objects from type "distance"
here is the method   distance add_distance(distance d1); \ in header file

```cpp
    distance distance::add_distance (distance d1) \\ implementation file
{
    distance sum;
    sum.feet = feet + d1.feet;
    sum.length = length + d1.length;
    return sum;
}
```

but during building the program it gives me an error that says "distance: ambiguous symbol"
anyone got a solution for this ???? ^^

Comment: Your error is caused by some other code that you didn't show us. Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ thinks it's caused by a conflict with the standard function called `distance`. Try renaming the class, or getting rid of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: And your edit changed what exactly now? Besides that is complete bogus code, and won't even compile, you should [edit] and provide a [mcve] if you believe my duplicate was wrongly chosen.